# SQL for reporting based on events

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting

I have an event table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
timestamp            |  station |  event_type   |  count
-----------------------------------------------------------
2013-02-22 01:00:00  |  1       |  log_in       |  -1
2013-02-22 01:05:00  |  1       |  alert        |  5
2013-02-22 01:08:00  |  1       |  alert        |  3
2013-02-22 01:10:00  |  1       |  log_out      |  -1
2013-02-22 01:30:00  |  2       |  log_in       |  -1
2013-02-22 01:31:00  |  2       |  alert        |  2
2013-02-22 01:35:00  |  2       |  log_out      |  -1
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I write an SQL to produce a report like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
station  | log_in               |  log_out               | count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 2013-02-22 01:00:00  |  2013-02-22 01:10:00   | 8
2        | 2013-02-22 01:30:00  |  2013-02-22 01:35:00   | 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I want to sum up the alerts in between the log ins and outs.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Update:

JW's answer below works, but I made a mistake in the table above. For the alert events, I do not know the station id, so the table should be like the below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
timestamp            |  station |  event_type   |  count
-----------------------------------------------------------
2013-02-22 01:00:00  |  1       |  log_in       |  -1
2013-02-22 01:05:00  |  -1      |  alert        |  5
2013-02-22 01:08:00  |  -1      |  alert        |  3
2013-02-22 01:10:00  |  1       |  log_out      |  -1
2013-02-22 01:30:00  |  2       |  log_in       |  -1
2013-02-22 01:31:00  |  -1      |  alert        |  2
2013-02-22 01:35:00  |  2       |  log_out      |  -1
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What happens with the report if there is no log_out record corresponding to log_in record?

Comment: Ideally, the SQL should handle that case, ie the missing log_out is the same time as the last alert event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  station, 
        MIN(timestamp) login,
        MAX(timestamp) logout,
        SUM(CASE WHEN count > 0 THEN count ELSE 0 END) count
FROM    tbaleName
GROUP   BY station
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55e8e7/2)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.station, 
        a.login,
        a.logout,
        SUM(CASE WHEN count > 0 THEN count else 0 END) count
FROM
        (
          SELECT  station, 
                  MIN(timestamp) login,
                  MAX(timestamp) logout
          FROM    tableName2 
          GROUP   BY station
        ) a
        INNER JOIN tableName2 b
          ON b.timestamp BETWEEN a.logIN and a.logout AND
             a.station <> -1
GROUP   BY a.station, 
           a.login,
           a.logout
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61710/1)

for faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `timestamp`.

Comment: Hi JW, your answer is perfect, but I actually made a mistake in my original post. For the alert events, I do not know the station id. In this case, the group by station does not work.

Comment: and what is your desired result according from your new data?

Comment: Hi JW, the desired results is still the same. I just need to link the alert events by the timestamp instead of the station id.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: Hi JW, you are awesome! Your updated answer worked perfectly!! I am using MySQL.